# how to delete a char**

Tags: c++, pointers

I am basically wondering how to delete a double pointer, for example char**. This is because I ran into an access violation problem which I don't quite understand. Here is the code:

```
StatsManager::_statsNameList = new char*[StatsManager::MAX_STATS_COUNT*StatsManager::MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT*StatsManager::MAX_ROI_COUNT];

if(NULL != StatsManager::_statsNameList )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < StatsManager::MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT; i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < StatsManager::MAX_ROI_COUNT; j++ )
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < StatsManager::MAX_STATS_COUNT; k++ )
                {
                    char* pList = StatsManager::_statsNameList[i*area + j*StatsManager::MAX_STATS_COUNT + k];
                    if (NULL != pList)
                    {
                       // following line is where the exception throws
                        delete[] StatsManager::_statsNameList[i*area + j*StatsManager::MAX_STATS_COUNT + k];
                        StatsManager::_statsNameList[i*area + j*StatsManager::MAX_STATS_COUNT + k] = NULL;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    delete[] StatsManager::_statsNameList;
    StatsManager::_statsNameList = NULL;
```

I am very confused because for the inner loop where the exception throws, I watched the pLsit is a bad pointer, so how come the `if (NULL != pList)` still get passed?

And what is the correct way to delete a `char**`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you have one `new` statement and two `delete` statements , that should tell you something :)

Comment: correct way: use container classes (e.g. `std::vector`) and `std::string`, or at the very least use smart pointers.

Comment: @Raxvan but I think the second delete should not be hit because it is bad pointer?

Comment: @crashmstr you mean no way to use char**?

Comment: @Ono So you allocate a bunch of memory and you delete it at the end (seems legit so far), however the delete in the middle is delete what memory (where do you allocate that memory that is supposed to be deleted there)?

Comment: @Ono, you *can*, but the question is *should* you. C++ gives you many ways of handing this. Use `std::string` for strings instead of C-style strings. Use container classes like `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. And if you need to allocate memory, use smart pointers to make that easier.

Comment: I don't understand why this thread is downvoted? I am confused about this problem, and I am seeking help here. Is that wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "bad pointer"? If it's anything other than the null pointer, then of course it will be unequal to the null pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo the watch windows shows <Bad Ptr>. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Ono Yes. You need to either allocate memory for every pointer in the array, or set it to `NULL`. If you `delete` something random, bad things happen.

Comment: @molbdnilo I see. I will do that. Thanks! Put your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Baldrickk I think it owns it.

Comment: The only way to delete a pointer is to delete the object that contains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you have to follow two points:

- If you used `new[]` for allocation use `delete[]` for deallocation, and if `new` was used for allocation `delete` has to be used to free the memory;
- You have to free the memory on every level it was allocated, e.g.

  ```
  int **pp = new *int;
  *pp = new int;
  **pp = 5;

  delete *pp;
  delete pp;
  ```

So, `delete` of the same type as `new` has to called the same number of times, but in reverse order.

Comment: So for my case it should be a loop, within which to delete[] every char*?

Comment: @Ono pay close attention to the second new statement (`*pp = new int;`) , you are missing that one in your code. `int ** pp` is a pointer of pointer of int, each pointer level  must be allocated if you want to delete it

Comment: I see. so I should new[] a char* for every item within char** before the delete the whole char**, am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @ Ono. Yes, you should `new` (if not an array) or `new[]` (if an array) for every `char*`. Then you should use the same variation of the delete operator in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer is the one makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `delete` or `delete[]` operator that matches the operator used to allocate. So `new[]` is followed by `delete[]`, and `new` by `delete`.

You cannot delete a `char**`, it's just a pointer to a pointer to a char. It depends on the object it's actually holding. Logically, a `char**` would itself contain an array like `new char*[x]`, and is itself filled with objects allocated with `new char[x]`. In that case you need to loop over the array and `delete[]` those, then `delete[]` the outer array.

Comment: I think it is what I did? Loop though the outer list to delete everyone inside?